# Bookmarklet in JavaScript to toggle Gmail conversation view

Tags: javascript, jquery, gmail

I want a bookmarklet to quickly toggle the Gmail conversation view on and off.

Starting from [@seahorsepip's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31639592/gmail-conversation-view-toggle-bookmarketlet-favelet-scriptlet), I have:

```
javascript:window.location.href = "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general";setTimeout(function(){document.querySelector("div.AO table tbody tr:nth-child(8) table:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(1) input:not(:checked)").click();document.querySelector("[guidedhelpid=save_changes_button]").click();}, 1000);
```

The problem is that I need two bookmarklets.

Selector `.AO tr:nth-child(8) table:nth-child(1) input` selects the "Conversation ON" button; and `.AO tr:nth-child(8) table:nth-child(2) input` selects "Conversation OFF".

Is there a way to have one bookmarklet that will check the one that is not checked? (If I run the "wrong" one I see `Cannot read property 'click' of null` in console.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add a condition to your bookmarklet, checking if

```
document.querySelector("div.AO table tbody tr:nth-child(8) table:nth-of-type(2) input").checked
```

isn't `null`:

```
window.location.href = "https://mail.google.com" + window.location.pathname + "#settings/general";
sBase = "div.AO table tbody tr:nth-child(8) table:nth-of-type(";
sOn = sBase + "1) input";
sOff = sBase + "2) input";

setTimeout(function(){
    if (document.querySelector(sOff).checked)
        document.querySelector(sOn).click();
    else
        document.querySelector(sOff).click();
    document.querySelector("[guidedhelpid=save_changes_button]").click();
}, 1000);
```

Giving:

```
javascript:window.location.href="https://mail.google.com"+window.location.pathname+"#settings/general";sBase="div.AO table tbody tr:nth-child(8) table:nth-of-type(";sOn=sBase+"1) input";sOff=sBase+"2) input";setTimeout(function(){if(document.querySelector(sOff).checked) document.querySelector(sOn).click();else document.querySelector(sOff).click();document.querySelector("[guidedhelpid=save_changes_button]").click()},1000)
```

Comment: My first version was missing a `)`, can you try with the new version by reloading the page?

Comment: Thanks! That works to switch from ON to OFF; but if run it again I get `Cannot read property 'click' of null`

Comment: Can you add `console.log(document.querySelector("[guidedhelpid=save_changes_button]"));` before `document.querySelector("[guidedhelpid=save_changes_button]").click();` to see if the problems comes from here? Tell me what you get in your console.

Comment: `<button id=":of" guidedhelpid="save_changes_button" disabled="">Save Changes</button>` but only when switching from ON to OFF; otherwise `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:471`

Comment: I was testing without even using the 'save' line; just to see if the toggling works. And it only worked going from ON to OFF.

Comment: @Ze'ev Give me some time to debug this, I'll get back to you.

Comment: Freakin' sweet! You rock!

Comment: I added a bit to make it work in any of multiple G accounts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166572/discussion-between-zeev-and-zenoo).

Comment: This doesn't work anymore ... has anyone tweaked it for latest Gmail?